# Inequality for 2-associated Stirling numbers of the second kind

Tags: co.combinatorics, partitions, stirling-numbers

Let $S_2(n,k)$ denote the 2-associated Stirling number of the second kind for $n$ objects and $k$ blocks, with $n$ being at least two. That is, we partition $n$ labeled objects into $k$ unlabeled blocks such that each block has at least two objects in it, and $S_2(n,k)$ is the number of those partitions. I’d like to ask if the following is known:  q(n,k) is strictly decreasing in k ,where q(n,k):=S_2(n,k)/S(n,k), and  S is the Stirling number of the second kind. Many thanks for the help!